# OpenAI API max_tokens counting

Tags: token, openai-api

I am having a really strange issue. I am running this curl request, sending a simple `hi` message to `gpt-4`. The maximum context length of the models is 8192. `hi` should be 1 token (you can check here - https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer). That means I can set `max_tokens` to `8192 - 1 = 8191`.

However, OpenAI's API calculates that my messages take 8 tokens. Why?

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer sk-bla-bla-bla" \
  -d '{
    "model": "gpt-4",
    "max_tokens": 8191,
    "messages": [
      {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "hi"
      }
    ]
  }'
{
  "error": {
    "message": "This model's maximum context length is 8192 tokens. However, you requested 8199 tokens (8 in the messages, 8191 in the completion). Please reduce the length of the messages or completion.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": "messages",
    "code": "context_length_exceeded"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer here, crazy:
https://community.openai.com/t/what-is-the-reason-for-adding-total-7-tokens/337002